# Using AWS X-Ray in .NET Core 2.0 Applications

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0, aws-xray

There is a lot of documentation out there for using AWS in .NET Applications, but nowhere does it mention .NET Core 2.0. There is a [nuget library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.XRay) for .NET Core, however I can't find any documentation anywhere.

There is also a [ReInvent session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfF1E2RJ6Do) where they talk about X-Ray in .NET Core (starts around 19:30), but I cannot even find the libraries that they are using in the video.

Does anyone know of any useful resources?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE: https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet
AWS X-Ray .Net Core repo**

The Nuget package you linked is the AWS SDK .Net Core for AWS X-Ray (an AWS SDK standalone package for utilizing our service APIs). What you're looking for the the AWS X-Ray SDK .Net Core package for application instrumentation.

We're currently working on .Net Core, as you have seen from the re:invent panel, and the library has not been released yet. Expect more news coming soon.

Please stay tuned to our forums for new announcements: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forum.jspa?forumID=241&start=0

Comment: Thank you for your answer Sandra. I'm looking forward to more .Net Core 2.0 support